Apple Music App 1.4.4 / Album covers for m4a files missing
So, album art fail to show in Apple Music App for m4a albums and songs. Works for all other formats.
I can re-add, album for album, but that will take me forever.
Anyone know of a way to fix this bug? Do not want to auto import through apple music.
Quite funny that its apple lossless of all formats, that fail to work.
